# How do I get a Yongnuo YN-685 to wirelessly fire in MULTI with the YN622N-TX?

Tags: yongnuo, wireless-flash, stroboscopic-flash, slave-flash

I would like to use this setup so that two flashes both fire multiple times until the shutter closes. I can get the flashes to do this individually when attached to the camera, and I can get both to fire once, triggered by the YN622-TX transmitter, but cannot find a way to combine these functions. If any member has an answer, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are you talking about High Speed Sync (HSS) or 'Multi' flash?

Comment: What camera are you using?

Comment: I am using a Nikon D500. The flash setting is Multi Mode (p13 in manual) which has a setting for the numbers of flashes as "---" which keeps it flashing until the shutter closes.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it wirelessly with Nikon, which doesn't have the in-camera flash settings menu the way Canon does, unless there's been a firmware update for the YN622N-TX recently.

Comment: Have you tried setting the 'Multi' mode up on the flash *before* you put it into '622 Remote - Slave' mode? My Canon version lets me do that, and 'Multi' continues to show on the display, along with '622 Remote -Slave' after I press and hold the mode button. But the settings in my camera override that when I half press the shutter. Since Nikon bodies do not have internal flash control settings, if it doesn't send anything to override it, that might work with a Nikon camera.

Answer (score 2):

Read the manual, it is all there although not super easy to understand. I have YN685 lights, this is how I get them to work in Stoboscopic mode remotely with a YN622C-TX. Put the lights into 622 slave mode. On the 622-TX press and hold the Mode/EM button (note: press AND HOLD not just press). It will display "TTL" in the top middle of the display. Press and hold this button again, it will then display "Multi". When in this Multi mode, short press the GR/* button to scroll through to the flash power, the HZ or the total number of flashes and use the four buttons up/down and left/right to change these settings once selected. Press your camera shutter release to test. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've been able to get 'Multi (Stroboscopic) Flash' to work wirelessly via a YN622-TX is to set the multi settings via the in-camera flash menu of my Canon camera with the YN622C-TX set to 'Manual' for the group(s) I'm using in 'Multi' mode.

- The flash should be set to '622 Remote - Slave'. The initial settings on the flash should be the "neutral" values: Power to 1/1, FEC to '0', and zoom to 'Auto'.
- The YN622C-TX should be set to 'M' (manual) mode.
- If you want to set the power level of each flash to a different level, then use the control panel on each flash to assign each flash to a different group.
- You can set the power level via the YN622C-TX or via the camera's internal menu.
- Use the camera's flash menu [External Speedlite control] → [Flash function settings] to bring up the flash function settings screen.
- Set the cursor over the upper left corner, press the 'Set' button, and change the mode to 'Multi' and press 'Set' again.
- Once 'Multi is selected, use the 'Quick Control Wheel' or the 'Joystick' to navigate directly below 'Multi'.
- Set the cursor over the number for 'Flash count' on the far left and press 'Set'. Use the 'Quick Control Wheel' or the 'Joystick' up or down to select how many flash pulses you want to fire. Setting the value to [--] will cause the flash to fire at the set frequency for as long as the shutter is open. Once the value is at the desired setting, press 'Set'.
- Navigate to the immediate right, set the cursor over 'Flash frequency', press 'Set', and use the 'Quick Control Wheel' or the 'Joystick' up or down to select the number of pulses per second. (Selecting '1' will fire one pulse per second. Selecting '2' will fire two per second/one every half second. Selecting '3' will fire three per second/one every one-third second, and so on.) The lowest value that can be set is '1', so pulses more than one second apart are not possible. The highest setting is '500'.
- Be sure your set shutter time/speed is long enough to allow the number of pulses you have selected to fire at the intervals you have selected.

As long as I don't change the power level setting via the YN622C-TX, the flash will pulse per my settings each time I take a photo. If the power level (or any other setting) is changed everything will revert from "multi' to 'Manual' (with one pulse per picture). I'll then have to go back into the camera's menu to change it back to 'Multi'.

Since we now know you are using a Nikon camera, you can't use the camera's internal flash menu that Nikons don't offer. But that may actually be a way around why I have to do it that way with my Canon cameras. If the camera has no internal settings to override the settings on the flash, what you set on the flash before you put it in '622 Remote - Slave' mode may be preserved and allow you to set the 'Multi (Scroposcopic) flash' in the flash directly before pressing the mode button for a few seconds to put it into '622 Remote - Slave' mode.

Have you tried setting the 'Multi' mode up on the flash before you put it into '622 Remote - Slave' mode? My Canon version lets me do that, and 'Multi' continues to show on the display, along with '622 Remote -Slave' after I press and hold the mode button. But the internal flash settings in my camera override that when I half press the shutter. Since Nikon bodies do not have internal flash control menus, if it doesn't send anything to override it, that might work with a Nikon camera.

Comment: Michael Thanks for all the input. Unfortunately as soon as the flash is set to Slave mode, the settings revert back to a single flash.

Comment: Hmm. With my Canon version of the YN685. It still displays 'Multi' until it receives the signal from a shutter button half press. If you've got a version of the YN622N-TX with a USB port, there might be a firmware update that allows you to use 'Multi' wirelessly. MY YN622C-TX is late 2014 vintage and had a mini-USB port.